# MySQLに接続するためのPHPのライブラリ

Tags: php, mysql

MySQLに接続するためのPHPのライブラリはありますか？ 自作ではふつう作らないと聞いたのですが

Comment: 「自作ではふつう作らない」と言っているのは誰ですか？その人に直接質問するのも一つの方法かと思います。

Comment: 「SQL」が何を指しているかも曖昧ですので、より明確にしないと第三者には答えられないです。

Comment: My SQLです